# Custom View with dynamic visible Range

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to build a custom view with Fullcalendar with the following features:

- The view I want to show is similar to the "timelineMonth" view, with the difference that it should start 3 days before the 1st of the requested month, and should end 3 days after the last day of the requested month. It's a sort of "extendedMonth" View
- I also require that the first visible day is the first of the month (and the 3 days before the first will be visible through scrolling)
- the view title should be the name of the requested month (not the range of the 3 months showed)

I've tried with custom Views example with visible range option, but I can't find the correct configuration.

This is my current code. The date range is correct, but the first visibile day is not the first offline the month (it's the -3 days) and the title shows the range of months (example: aug-oct)

```
views: {
    extendedMonth: {
      type: 'timeline',
      dateAlignment: 'month',
      titleFormat: 'MMM',
      visibleRange: function(currentDate) {

        var startOfMonth = currentDate.clone().startOf('month');
        var endOfMonth = currentDate.clone().endOf('month');

        return {
          start: startOfMonth.clone().subtract(2, 'days'),
          end: endOfMonth.clone().add(2, 'days') 
        };
  },
      buttonText: 'Extended Month'
 }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: what's it doing / not doing that you didn't want it to? Make it easy for us to help you - try and be more specific than "can't get it right". Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my question! Thanks

Comment: Ok thanks. The first day shown will always be the first day available in the timeline. AFAIK there is no way to change that in the timeline view. It's been asked on StackOverflow before. I see you used dateAlignment, but https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dateAlignment says "If a view’s range is explicity defined with visibleRange, dateAlignment will be ignored." Perhaps you could make a feature request to the fullCalendar maintainers, if no-one has done so already.

Comment: As for the title, what do you mean by the "requested month"? You mean the month into which `currentDate` falls? You could potentially alter the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/titleFormat setting to see if you can get that working.